# How do I access db rows from python?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Noob, trying to figure out how to get access to entries in my sqlite database from within my application.py file. In a nutshell, I'm trying to add a new user and hashed password to my db, then keep the user logged in. I'm using a lot of the same code from the login function given (CS50 Finance project), but am getting a 'list index out of range' error, meaning I am not accessing the row properly. Simple answers (that I can understand) are preferred to complex ones that I can't.

I've searched on here and on the interwebs without success.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Query database for username (it should not be there if new user)
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
        username=request.form.get("username"))
        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        if len(rows) != 0:
            return apology("Username is already in use, please choose a unique username", 403)
        else:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)", username=request.form.get("username"), hash=hash)

        # Problem is with the below line (copied from Login function): 
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: try to print the ```session["user_id"]``` and see what it's showing up. I thing the problem it's the ```session.clear()``` command

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger or generating output at various steps along the way? What do you expect `rows` to be after the inner if/else block?

Comment: I can use the form to insert into the database, i.e. 'newuser' & 'newpass'. I then simply want to set the sql user equal to the session_id, so that the user remains logged in. (But no, not sure how to use the CS50 debugger).

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I forgot to again query my sql database, hence the correct code is below:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():

    # Forget any other user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Query database to see if it already contains the username, with username being posted from HTML page
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.get("username"))
        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))

        # Case where username already exists in database
        if len(rows) != 0:
            return apology("Username is already in use, please choose a unique username", 403)
        # Else insert name into database
        else:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)", username=request.form.get("username"), hash=hash)

        # Now pull that user from the database
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: You could do it that way too! If you capture the new id when you insert, you save a db read. Not particularly crucial in this exercise, but often very important in business or web software.